# How do I set up Jupyter/IPython Notebook for Django?

Tags: django, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have been using the method described in [this post](https://andrewbrookins.com/python/using-ipython-notebook-with-django/) for setting up IPython Notebook to play nicely with Django. The gist of the method is to create an IPython extension which sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and runs django.setup() when IPython starts.

The code for the extension is:

```
def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    # The `ipython` argument is the currently active `InteractiveShell`
    # instance, which can be used in any way. This allows you to register
    # new magics or aliases, for example.
    try:
        import os
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
        import django
        django.setup()
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

With a recent upgrade to Jupyter Notebook this setup is now broken for me. I am able to run Django code in the Jupyter notebook by adding a similar bit of code to the first cell of the notebook. However, I was not able to figure out how to get Jupyter to run the extension automatically so I would not have to do this again for each and every notebook I am creating.

What should I do to get Django and Jupyter to play nicely?

**UPDATE:**
For @DarkLight - I am using Django 1.8.5 with Jupyter 1.0.0. The code I run in the notebook is:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/project')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settingsfile")
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? Django shell_plus --notebook doesn't work for me, show apps not loaded error.

Comment: @DarkLight - I ended up running the commands from a script, which I added to the first cell in each new notebook. Not very pretty, but it works.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of django, ipthon and jupyter you are using, along with code you are using (If it is not the same as in the answer). Because for me, the django.setup() call just results in that ipython cell hanging.

Comment: It finally works when I set DEBUG=False in my settings file. Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: @DarkLight no idea about the debug=False. I have run this on my dev environment which uses debug=True without a problem. I will update the question shortly with the information you have asked.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just for completeness (but it's 2018, so maybe things changed since this question was posted): you can actually install a Jupyter Python kernel in your Django environment that will then connect (run under) a different Jupyter server/environment (one where you've installed widgets, extensions, changed the theme, etc.). `django_extensions` right now still does only part of the required work :-)

This assumes you have a Jupyter virtual environment that's separate from Django's one and whose kernels/extensions are installed with `--user`. All the Jupyter extensions (and their dependencies) are installed in this venv instead of the Django's one/ones (you'll still need pandas, matplotlib, etc. in the Django environment if you need to use them together with Django code).

In your Django virtual environment (that can run a different version of Python, including a version 2 interpreter) install the ipython kernel:

```
pip install -U ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name='environment_name' --display-name='Your Project'
```

This will create a kernel configuration directory with the specified -–name in your user’s Jupyter kernel directory (on Linux it *was* `~/.jupyter/kernels` but in 2023 it became `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/`,  while on OSX it’s `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels`) containing its kernel.json file and images/icons (by default the default Jupyter icon for the kernel we’re installing are used). This kernel will run inside the virtual environment what was active at creation, thus using the exact same version of python and all the installed modules used by our Django project.

Running `./manage.py shell_plus --notebook` does something very similar, but in addition to requiring everything (including the Jupyter server and all the extensions) installed in the current venv, it’s also unable to run notebooks in directories different from the project’s root (the one containing `./manage.py`). In addition it’ll run the kernel using the first executable called python it finds on the path, not the virtual environment’s one, making it misbehave when not started from the command line inside an active Django virtual environment.

To fix these problems so that we're able to create a Notebook running inside any Django project we have so configured and to be able to run notebooks stored anywhere on the filesystem, we need to:

1. make sure the first ‘argv’ parameter contains the full path to the python interpreter contained in the virtual environment
2. add (if not already present) an ‘env’ section that will contain shell environment variables, then use these to tell Python where to find our project and which Django settings it should use. We do this by adding something like the following:

```
   "env": {
      "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "my_project.settings",
      "PYTHONPATH": "$PYTHONPATH:/home/projectuser/projectfolder/my_project"
   }
```

3. optional: change ‘display_name’ to be human friendly and replace the icons.

editing this environment kernel.json file you'll see something similar:

```
{
 "display_name": "My Project", 
 "language": "python", 
 "env": {
  "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "my_project.settings",
  "PYTHONPATH": "$PYTHONPATH:/home/projectuser/projectfolder/my_project"
 },
 "argv": [
  "/home/projectuser/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/envs/my_project_venv/bin/python", 
  "-m", 
  "ipykernel_launcher", 
  "-f", 
  "{connection_file}",
  "--ext",
  "django_extensions.management.notebook_extension"
 ]
}
```

Notable lines:

- **"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "my_project.settings"**: your settings, usually as seen inside your project's manage.py
- **"PYTHONPATH": "$PYTHONPATH:/home/projectuser/projectfolder/my_project"**: PYTHONPATH is extended to include your project's main directory (the one containing manage.py) so that settings can be found even if the kernel isn't run in that exact directory (here django_extensions will use a generic `python`, thus running the wrong virtual environment unless the whole Jupyter server is launched from inside it: adding this to the kernel.json created by django_extensions will enable it to run notebooks anywhere in the Django project directory)
- **"/home/projectuser/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/envs/my_project_venv/bin/python"**: first argument (argv list) of the kernel execution, should be the full path to your project's virtual environment's python interpreter (this is another thing django_extensions gets wrong: fixing this will allow any notebook server to run that specific Django environment's kernel with all its installed modules)
- **"django_extensions.management.notebook_extension"**: this is the extension that will load the 'shell_plus' functionality in the notebook (optional but useful :-) )

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks! That's definitely the best setup. In case it's not clear, find kernel.json at ~/Library/Jupyter/{your-kernel-name}/ (for Mac) and similarly inside ~/.jupyter/ for Linux.

Comment: Isn't PYTHONPATH supposed to be the same with manage.py, so usually "/home/user/devel/my_project" instead of "...my_project/myproject" ?

Comment: @NguyễnTrọngTín yes, but that depends on how you structure your projects... we have a double project_name folder that above Django's, to contain non-django-related things. I agree it's confusing, I'll try to edit the example

Comment: Perfect trick!
Just for completeness to avoid message: "Django: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async", here is what to add at the beginning of ipynb file before django.setup():
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926359/django-synchronousonlyoperation-you-cannot-call-this-from-an-async-context-u

Answer (score 78):

1. Install `django-extensions` from https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/index.rst

   ```
    pip install django-extensions
   ```
2. Change your settings file to include 'django-extensions'

   ```
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_extensions']
   ```
3. Run your Django server like this:

   ```
   python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
   ```
4. alter to suit, and run this in your first cell

   ```
   import os, sys
   PWD = os.getenv('PWD')
   os.chdir(PWD)
   sys.path.insert(0, os.getenv('PWD'))
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings.py")
   import django
   django.setup()
   ```
5. Now you should be able to import your django models etc. eg:

   ```
   from app.models import Foobar
   Foobar.objects.all()
   ```

Comment: it works even without point 4 if you create notebook with "Django Shell-Plus" kernel

Comment: and importantly it has some dependencies: `ipython`, `jupyter`. You can install them

`pip install ipython`,`pip install jupyter`

Comment: If you are using `django-configurations`, make use to get this right: https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#ipython-notebooks

Comment: @igo In my case, I'm here since, it didn't work without point 4. I would also suggest alternate point 5. Instead of importing models, one can add a cell, then copy paste those import statements from `python manage.py runserver`. Then they can use models without the importing manually.

Comment: I am able to go through the point 3 but then notebook opened in my browser does not connect to kernel and gives error of connection failed. can you help? @igo

Answer (score 25):

Here's what just worked for me

1. [install Django Extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html) (I used 1.9.6) as per other answers
2. install jupyter
   `pip install jupyter`
3. some stuff I did to setup jupyter inside my Docker container -- see below if this applies to you †
4. from your base Django directory, create a directory for notebooks, e.g. 
   `mkdir notebooks`
5. Go to that directory 
   `cd notebooks`
6. start django extensions shell_plus from inside that directory: 
   `../manage.py shell_plus --notebook`

    The notebook server should now be running, and may launch a new browser.  If it doesn't launch a browser window, follow the instructions to paste a link or a token.
7. from the browser, open a new "Django Shell Plus" notebook, as per John Mee's answer's screenshot

**AND**, importantly, what *didn't* work was changing directories from inside the notebook environment.  If I tried to work with any notebook that was not in the directory that `manage.py shell_plus --notebook` was run in, then the kernal was not configured correctly.  For me, having the notebook be configured for just a single directory at a time was good enough.  If you need a more robust solution, you should be able set `PYTHONPATH` prior to starting jupyter.  For example add `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/django/project"` to a virtualenv activate script.  But I haven't tried this.

### † Docker Setup (optional)

1. add a port mapping for your container for port 8888

For example, in your docker compose file;

```
ports:
      -  "8890:8888"
```

2. Configure your project settings file to use ip 0.0.0.0

This is what I did:

```
NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
    '--ip', '0.0.0.0', 
    '--allow-root',
    '--no-browser', 
]
```

Comment: When you cd to `notebooks`, do you have a `manage.py` in that directory or how do you run it from there?

Comment: I must have manage.py added to my PATY-- maybe try django-admin.py instead.

Comment: Try running `../manage.py shell_plus --notebook` note the `../`.  Works fine for me Django 2.1.

Comment: The NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS part was key for me, thank you!

Answer (score 17):

**Note:** I am using Python 3.7 and Django 2.1, it works for **Django 2.2**. I don't have to run anything in my first cell, and this works like charm as long as you don't mind having the notebooks in the root of your Django project.

It is assumed that you *have a virtual environment* for your project, and it is activated. I use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create virtual environments and track dependencies of my python projects, but it is up to you what tool you use.

It is also assumed that *you have created a Django project* and your *current working directory is the root of this project*.

### Steps

1. Install `jupyter`

   **Using pip**

   ```sh
   pip install jupyter
   ```

   **Using pipenv**

   ```sh
   pipenv install jupyter
   ```
2. Install `django-extentions`

   **Using pip**

   ```sh
   pip install django-extensions
   ```

   **Using pipenv**

   ```sh
   pipenv install django-extensions
   ```
3. Set up `django-extensions` by adding it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting of your Django project `settings.py` file.:

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       ...
       'django_extensions',
   )
   ```
4. Run the [`shell_plus`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html) management command that is part of `django-extensions`. Use the option `--notebook` to start a notebook:

   ```sh
   python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
   ```

   Jupyter Notebooks will open automatically in your browser.
5. Start a new Django Shell-Plus notebook

[image]

That's it!

---

Again, you don't have to run anything in the first cell, and you can corroborate by running `dir()` to see the names in the current local scope.

[image]

#### Edit:

If you want to put your notebooks in a directory called `notebooks` at the root directory, you can do the following:

```
$ mkdir notebooks && cd notebooks
$ python ../manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Thanks to Mark Chackerian whose answer provided the idea to make run the notebooks in a directory other than the project's root.

These are the modules that are imported automatically thanks to `shell_plus`:

```
# Shell Plus Model Imports
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
# Shell Plus Django Imports
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Avg, Case, Count, F, Max, Min, Prefetch, Q, Sum, When, Exists, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
```

Comment: I kept my not book in a directory of an app and was running `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook` from root and that causing error `myproject module not found` and notebook was not working properly, following the suggesting I ran the notebook from the directory `python ../../manage.py shell_plus --notebook` and everything is working fine now - thanks! @Imiguelvargasf

Answer (score 10):

Actually turns out you (*might not*) need to do all that crap.  Just install django-extensions and run jupyter!

```
(myprojectvenv)$ cd myproject    
(myprojectvenv)$ pip install jupyter
(myprojectvenv)$ pip install django-extensions
(myprojectvenv)$ jupyter notebook
```

In the browser, start a new "Django Shell-Plus":
[image]

And you should be good to go.  eg:

```
from myproject.models import Foobar
Foobar.objects.all()
```

Comment: Make sure you also have jupyter installed in the virtualenv `pip install jupyter`

Comment: Actually turns out you *do* need to do all that crap. Your method doesn't work in a clean environment. You probably have other assumptions and/or state you're not expressing in your simpler answer.

Comment: This worked for me the first time I tried it, and then it didn't work the second (!?) The difference, it turns out, between working and not working, was the path of the notebook file.  So, this answer could be fine if you want to keep your notebook files in the top directory of your project -- that is the "assumption" of the earlier comment.

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer from RobM works, it was less clear than it could be and has a few unnecessary steps. Simply put, to run notebooks through Django *from a notebook environment outside of the project directory*:

Install:

```
 pip install django-extensions
```

Add `'django-extensions'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`

```
 INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_extensions']
```

Run a notebook from within Django, then close it:

```
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

This will create your kernel, which we will now edit to point to an absolute path of Python rather than a relative path.

On OSX, the kernel file is at: `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels/django_extensions/kernel.json`

On Linux: `~/.jupyter/kernels/django_extensions/kernel.json`

We only need to make two changes:

The first is to edit the first value in the `"argv"` list from `"python"` to the full address of the python version in your Django virtual environment. E.g.: `"/Users/$USERNAME/Documents/PROJECT_FOLDER/venv/bin/python"`

Secondly, to the `"env"` dictionary, add `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "mysite.settings",` where `mysite` is the folder that contains your Django settings.

Optionally, change the value of `"display_name"`.

Now when you run a notebook from any directory, choosing the `"Django Shell-Plus"` kernel will allow your notebooks to interact with Django. Any packages such as pandas will need to be installed in the Django venv.

Answer (score 3):

The following does work for me using win10, Python 3.5, Django 1.10:

- Install Python with the Anaconda distribution so **Jupyter** will be installed as well
- Install **Django** and install **django-extensions**:

  ```
  pip install Django

  pip install django-extensions
  ```
- Start a new Django project. You have to do that in that part of your tree of directories which can be accessed by Jupyter later.

  ```
  django-admin startproject _myDjangoProject_
  ```
- Start Jypter
- navigate Jupyter to the directory *myDjangoProject* and enter the first/top *myDjangoProject*-directory
- Start within the first/top *myDjangoProject*-directory a new Jupyter noteboke: *new --> Django Shell-Plus*
- enter and run the following piece of code :

  ```
  import os
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myDjangoProject.settings")
  import django
  django.setup()
  ```
- Note that this piece of code is the same as in *manage.py*, and note that "myDjangoProject.settings" points to *myDjangoProject/settings.py*
- Now you can start with examples, e.g.:

  ```
  from django.template import Template, Context

  template = Template('The name of this project is {{ projectName }}')
  context = Context({'projectName': 'MyJypyterDjangoSite'})
  template.render(context)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command.

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project/root DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add some information to the very complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214033/555236) of RobM, for the benefit of the very rare developers that use [buildout](https://github.com/buildout/buildout) along with djangorecipe [djangorecipe](https://github.com/rvanlaar/djangorecipe) as I do... I refer to jupyter lab as I use that but I think all info can be applied to old jupyter notebooks.

When using buildout you end up with a 'bin/django' handler you'll use instead of 'manage.py'. That's the script that defines the whole path. I added one more part in my buildout.cfg:

```
[ipython]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =  ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:directory}/apps
initialization =  import os
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'web.settings'
```

so that another script named `ipython` will be created in `./bin` directory. I point kernelspec to that interpreter. Moreover I use `kernel` argument rather than `"-m",  "ipykernel_launcher"` so that the kernel definition I use is:

```
{
    "argv": [
        "/misc/src/hg/siti/trepalchi/bin/ipython",
        "kernel",
        "-f",
        "{connection_file}",
        "--ext",
        "django_extensions.management.notebook_extension"
    ],
    "display_name": "Trepalchi",
    "language": "python"
}
```

Due to how the ipython script is created by `buildout` there's no need to add environmental variables in my case.

As Rob already mentioned, jupiterlab is only installed in one environment where I start it with the command:

```
jupyter lab
```

not in the environment of Django project whare I only install `ipykernel` (that has already a bunch of 20 dependencies).

Since I tend to have quite a lot of projects I find it usefull to have a single point where I start `jupyter lab` with many links to the projects so that I can reach them easily. Thanks to the extension provided by django_extension I don't need any extra cell to initialize the notebook.

Any single kernel added in this way can be found with the command:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

And clearly listed in the launcher of jupyter lab