# Jupyter notebook with Django and Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to launch Jupyter notebook with Django so I can e.g. access Django database within Jupyter notebook.

I've read this post:

[How to setup Jupyter/IPython notebook for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483328/how-to-setup-jupyter-ipython-notebook-for-django)

but seems like its solutions assume working with Python 2. So when I run it I get an error "Could not find a kernel matching Python 2".

So, what are the steps to bind Jupyter notebook to Django application and Python3?

Comment: Does `SeanB` answer isn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Jupyter/IPython notebook for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483328/how-to-setup-jupyter-ipython-notebook-for-django)

Comment: Solution is here, and it works for Python 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856080/884640 If you are still getting an error it's something else in your setup. Try a fresh environment. Consider using `pyenv` if you are not using it yet. (_As well as_ virtualenv. They are not redundant.)