# Jupyter notebook in django

Tags: jupyter

My question might sound stupid, but yet I couldn't control my urge to ask. I am wondering how we can integrate Jupyter notebook in DJango application? Is it possible to convert notebook into html and then adding it to urls.py of the application.

I tried to take help of AI tools, Bard usggested me to use nbconvert in python interpreter. I couldnt find it. For reference, I am using visual studio code for django.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to convert and share. Alternatively, you could though just link to the notebook so that nbviewer will display a 'static' render of it. (I put 'static' in quotes because certain forms of interaction that are based on javascript, can continue to work within nbviewer, see [this example where the 'play' button works for the plot animation](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1). There are other directions. You could host JupyterLite instance as a static page as your part of your site and it should be an active notebook.

Comment: And back to your saying you couldn't find it, `jupyter nbconvert` is included as part of Jupyter. So if you been using it, you'd run it where you working with your `.ipynb` file. Then you'd move the created HTML file to your django-based site. Serving it as part of your static resources in your django site once the HTML is made is possible, too.

Comment: Plus, doesn't [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70229330/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35483328/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52752576/8508004) already cover your title?