# How to setup django shell kernel for jupyter notebook running in separate docker containers

Tags: python, django, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have several Django projects, each running in a docker container (each one having its own) on a single machine. I want to setup a Jupyter Notebook in a new container, and be able to have kernels for all these django projects (kernels that use their shell and environment). 
Any ideas?
I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214033/5230157) but this can only be used for when the django project and the jupyter notebook are running on the container :(

Comment: Yes, I have it running in different containers but the same image. So, you still have to install Jupyter on each image. But doesn't sound that this is what you want. You probably want one image with Jupyter separated from the Django images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after some researching and thinking, I came to the conclusion that this is in fact, almost impossible. I'll have to run an instance of jupyter notebook in each container.