# Django: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async

Tags: asynchronous, jupyter, django-3.0

I use Django 3.0.6 and Jupyter notebook running with `shell_plus --notebook`.

I try run queryset:

`User.objects.all()`

But return this error `SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async`.

I try this command

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

users = sync_to_async(User.objects.all())

for user in users:
    print(user)

TypeError: 'SyncToAsync' object is not iterable
```

The solution of Django documentation

`os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"` in settings.py is the unique solution?

Answer (score 82):

The error occurs because Jupyter notebooks has a running event loop.
From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/)

> If you try to run any of these parts from a thread where there is a running event loop, you will get a SynchronousOnlyOperation error. Note that you don’t have to be inside an async function directly to have this error occur. If you have called a synchronous function directly from an asynchronous function without going through something like sync_to_async() or a threadpool, then it can also occur, as your code is still running in an asynchronous context.

> If you encounter this error, you should fix your code to not call the offending code from an async context; instead, write your code that talks to async-unsafe in its own, synchronous function, and call that using asgiref.sync.sync_to_async(), or any other preferred way of running synchronous code in its own thread.

> If you are absolutely in dire need to run this code from an asynchronous context - for example, it is being forced on you by an external environment, and you are sure there is no chance of it being run concurrently (e.g. you are in a Jupyter notebook), then you can disable the warning with the DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE environment variable.

As the question is specific to jupyter notebook environment following is a valid solution.

```py
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rest.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
django.setup()
    
from users.models import User
User.objects.all()
```

One need to however by wary and not use it in production environment as per documentation warnings.

Comment: This answer is so much better than the top voted. No need to change the Django src.

Comment: Easy, but as pointed out in the docs, this may lead to data corruption: "If you accidentally try to call a part of Django that is still synchronous-only from an async view, you will trigger Django’s asynchronous safety protection to protect your data from corruption."

Comment: I need only these lines (when using 3.2rc1, if it matters):   

`import os`
`os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"`

Comment: Agree -- this is the simplest way to get a notebook running. After all, we're not actually running a service here, just using a notebook to poke around the Models, etc.

Answer (score 45):

`sync_to_async` takes a callable, not the result. Instead, you want this:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

users = sync_to_async(User.objects.all)()

for user in users:
    print(user)
```

You can also put the call(s) you want to wrap in a decorated function:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

@sync_to_async
def get_all_users():
    return User.objects.all()

for user in await get_all_users():
    print(user)
```

Note that this must be used from an async context, so a full example would look like:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

@sync_to_async
def get_all_users():
    return User.objects.all()

async def foo(request):
    for user in await get_all_users():
        print(user)
```

[Full documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/)

Comment: return this error. `<ipython-input-8-ade7a982ccf1>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SyncToAsync.__call__' was never awaited
  for user in get_all_users():
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ade7a982ccf1> in <module>
----> 1 for user in get_all_users():
      2     print(user)

TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable`

Comment: Your code `(for user in ...` needs to be inside an async function. You may also need to await it since you're turning it into a coroutine, such as `users = await get_all_users()`

Comment: But doesn't that lead to making the entire code async, not just the `foo` method? This would increase code complexity.

Answer (score 14):

You cant pass around a Queryset between sync and async functions since it is lazy.
You need to evaluate it inside a async context.

Like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
import asyncio


@sync_to_async
def get_users():
    return list(
        User.objects.all()
    )

async def user_loop():
    results = await get_users()
    for r in results:
        print(r.username)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(user_loop())
```

Comment: `list()` did the trick for me! thanks

Comment: Damn. Had I seen this 6h earlier.

Answer (score 6):

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async)

If you're trying to run any none-async parts of Django like ORM, you will get a SynchronousOnlyOperation error. Note that you don’t have to be inside an async function directly to have this error occur. If you have called a sync function directly from an async function, without using sync_to_async() or similar, then it can also occur. This is because your code is still running in a thread with an active event loop, even though it may not be declared as an async code.

You should use:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

def _get_blog(pk):
    return Blog.objects.get(pk=pk)

get_blog = await sync_to_async(_get_blog, thread_sensitive=True)(10)

....
```

Or

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

get_blog = await sync_to_async(Blog.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(10)
```

You can use database_sync_to_async of Django channel which is an improved sync_to_async function of asgiref.sync

for example:

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

get_blog = await database_sync_to_async(Blog.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(10)
```

Comment: I tried this: get_blog = await sync_to_async(Blog.objects.all(), thread_sensitive=True)
object SyncToAsync can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: if you are to use await, you have to use database_sync_to_async or sync_to_async inside an async function

Answer (score 0):

I just used this way to get all the user as normal sync method.

What is i done is

1. First i create a method the get all the query and then i iterate by for loop.
2. The for loop is only for put a time loop like time.sleep(seconds). The loop itself choose a time. If the queryset completely got in the users variable. The timer is started (i.e) the for loop.

   ```
    from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

    @sync_to_async
    def get_all_user():
        users = None
        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            '''
                timming loop. itself set a time by the time taken for iterate over the all User.objects.all()
            ''' 
            pass
        return users
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Django 4.1 added asynchronous iteration ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). To get all users in an async way, you can use this:

```py
users = []

async for u in User.objects.all():
    users.append(u)
```

or with a list comprehension:

```py
users = [u async for u in User.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find the answer from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/#async-safety

> If you try to run any of these parts from a thread where there is a running event loop, you will get a SynchronousOnlyOperation error. Note that you don’t have to be inside an async function directly to have this error occur. If you have called a sync function directly from an async function, without using sync_to_async() or similar, then it can also occur. This is because your code is still running in a thread with an active event loop, even though it may not be declared as async code.