# django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Upgraded python from 3.6 to 3.8.
Getting this error when I tried to connect to Django Admin.
Is this because of version change?
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 410, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 375, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 402, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 215, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 42, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 45, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
**django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.**```
````

Comment: what about your Django version?

Comment: The Django version is 3.1.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync\_to\_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926359/django-synchronousonlyoperation-you-cannot-call-this-from-an-async-context-u)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one environment variable(DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE) which is triggering this asyncio error. It is set as false by default.
What I did is is, in config.py I wrote {os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"}. And just bypassed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Upgrade to Django version 4 and see if this is solves
```

**Python compatibility¶**

```
Django 4.0 supports Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10. We highly recommend and only officially support the latest release of each series.


The Django 3.2.x series is the last to support Python 3.6 and 3.7.
```