# Sync to Async Django ORM queryset foreign key property

Tags: python-3.x, django, async-await, python-asyncio

Seemingly simple situation:
Django model has foreign key:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

In async context, I do:

```
# get invite with sync_to_async decorator, then
print(invite.inviter)
```

Get async's favorite error:

`You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async`

```
print(sync_to_async(invite.inviter)) # -> throws the same error
```

Sure, I can do:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_inviter(self, invite):
    return invite.inviter
```

But, this is senile, if I have to do this for every queryset property call.

Is there a sane way to handle this?

Perhaps, there is a way to do this for all calls like that at once?

Comment: Can you share how you queried for `invite`

Comment: `@sync_to_async
    def get_all_unaccepted_invites(self):
        return Invite.objects.filter(invitee=None)`

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926359/django-synchronousonlyoperation-you-cannot-call-this-from-an-async-context-u

Answer (score 4):

Yes, resolve the extra fields using `select_related`:

```py
# Good: pick the foreign_key fields using select_related
user = await Invite.objects.select_related('user').aget(key=key).user
```

Your other string *non-foreign* such as strings and ints attributes should already
exist on the model.

Won't work, (although they feel like they should)

```py
# Error django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation ... use sync_to_async
user = await Model.objects.aget(key=key).user
# Error (The field is actually missing from the `_state` fields cache.
user = await sync_to_async(Invite.objects.get)(key=key).user
```

---

**Other examples for research**

A standard `aget`, followed by a foreign key inspection yields a `SynchronousOnlyOperation` error.

I have a string `key`, and a ForeignKey `user` to the standard user model.

```py
class Invite(models.Model):
    user = fields.user_fk()
    key = fields.str_uuid()
```

An example with alternatives that mostly don't work:

```py
Invite = get_model('invites.Invite')
User = get_user_model()

def _get_invite(key):
    return Invite.objects.get(key=key)


async def invite_get(self, key):
    # (a) works, the related field is populated on response.
    user = await Invite.objects.select_related('user').aget(key=key).user
   

async def intermediate_examples(self, key):
    # works, but is clunky.
    user_id = await Invite.objects.aget(key=key).user_id
    # The `user_id` (any `_id` key) exists for a FK
    user = await User.objects.aget(id=user_id)


async def failure_examples(self, key):
    # (b) does not work. 
    user = await sync_to_async(Invite.objects.get)(key=key).user
    invite = await sync_to_async(Invite.objects.get)(key=key)

    # (c) these are not valid, although the error may say so.
    user = await invite.user
    user = await sync_to_async(invite.user)

    # same as the example (b)
    get_invite = sync_to_async(_get_invite, thread_sensitive=True)
    invite = get_invite(key)
    user = invite.user # Error 
    
    # (d) Does not populate the additional model
    user = await Invite.objects.aget(key=key).user # Error
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```py
> print(sync_to_async(invite.inviter))  # -> throws the same error
> ```

That's because it's equivalent to:

```py
i = invite.inviter  # -> throws the error here
af = sync_to_async(i)
print(af)
```

The correct usage is:

```py
f = lambda: invite.inviter
af = sync_to_async(f)
i = await af()
print(i)

# As a one-liner
print(await sync_to_async(lambda: invite.inviter)())
```

> Is there a sane way to handle this?
>
> Perhaps, there is a way to do this for all calls like that at once?

(Disclaimer: Not tested in production.)

With [nest_asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/), you could do this:

```py
def do(f):
    import nest_asyncio
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    return asyncio.run(sync_to_async(f)())


print(do(lambda: invite.inviter))
```

Or take it even further:

```py
class SynchronousOnlyAttributeHandler:
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        from django.core.exceptions import SynchronousOnlyOperation
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(item)
        except SynchronousOnlyOperation:
            from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
            import asyncio
            import nest_asyncio
            nest_asyncio.apply()
            return asyncio.run(sync_to_async(lambda: self.__getattribute__(item))())
```

```py
class Invite(models.Model, AsyncUnsafeAttributeHandler):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
```

```py
# Do this even in async context
print(invite.inviter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work? Instead of `invite.inviter` you do `await async_resolve_attributes(invite, "inviter")`

```py
@sync_to_async
def async_resolve_attributes(instance, *attributes):
    current_instance = instance
    for attribute in attributes:
        current_instance = getattr(current_instance, attribute)
    resolved_attribute = current_instance
    return resolved_attribute
```