# You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async. Django ORM

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I wrote the following code:

```
class BookmakerA:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bookmaker = None 
        
    async def _init(self):
        self.bookmaker, _ = await Bookmaker.objects.aget_or_create(name="BookmakerA", defaults={"name": "BookmakerA"})
```

I call this class from a Celery task which looks as follows:

```
@shared_task
def get_bookmaker_matches(): 
    start = time.time()

    bookmakera = BookmakerA() 
    
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    
    loop.run_until_complete(bookmakera._init())
```

This however results in the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Why does this happen and how do I resolve this.

Even if I put it like this:

```
await sync_to_async(Bookmaker.objects.get_or_create, thread_sensitive=True)(name="BookmakerA", defaults={"name": "BookmakerA"})
```

It results in the same error

Using Django 4.2.6 which supports async ORM (acreate_or_create, aget, so on)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync\_to\_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926359/django-synchronousonlyoperation-you-cannot-call-this-from-an-async-context-u)

Comment: @PaulCornelius Nope. Tried all of that and still end up on the same exception