How to make Django template variables work async?
I'm trying to apply Async approach to an existing Django project, updating views appears this error: django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
views.py
@sync_to_async
def get_educations():
  return Education.objects.filter(highlight=True).order_by("-order")

async def home(request):
  return render(request, "home.html", {
    "educations": await get_educations(),
  })

home.html
<section class="d-flex flex-column">
<h3 class="section">Education</h3>
{% for education in educations %}
  {% include "preview_education.html" %}
{% endfor %}

Trying with return [Education.objects.first()]works well.
Any idea how to solve it ?

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158272/10951070.  Education.objects.filter(highlight=True).order_by("-order") returns a QuerySet, which doesn't return anything until it is evaluated. Try something that does, for example, return list(Education.objects.filter(highlight=True).order_by("-order")).

return [Education.objects.first()] works because .first() returns an object, which is why it worked.

The solutions is to cast Django Queryset to list and use select_related with the model relations.
views.py:
@sync_to_async
def get_educations():
  return list(
    Education.objects.filter(
      highlight=True
    )
    .select_related('organization')
    .order_by("-order")
  )

async def home(request):
  return render(request, "home.html", {
    "educations": await get_educations()
  }

home.html:
<section class="d-flex flex-column">
  <h3 class="section">Education</h3>
  {% for education in educations %}
    <article class="element">
      <h4>{{ education.name }}</h4>
      <p>{{ education.organization }}</p>
      <p>{{ education.place }}</p>
      <p>{{ education.duration }}</p>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>

