# Django shell_plus: How to access Jupyter notebook in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I am trying to access a Jupyter Notebook created with the `shell_plus` command from django-extensions in a Docker container.

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

My configuration is based on the answers of @RobM and @Mark Chackerian to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483328/how-do-i-set-up-jupyter-ipython-notebook-for-django). I.e. I installed and configured a custom kernel and my Django apps config file has the constant `NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS` set to:

```
NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
    '--ip', '0.0.0.0',
    '--port', '8888',
    '--allow-root',
    '--no-browser',
]
```

I can see the container starting successfully in the logs:

```
[I 12:58:54.877 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 12:58:54.877 NotebookApp] http://10d56bab37fc:8888/?token=b2678617ff4dcac7245d236b6302e57ba83a71cb6ea558c6
[I 12:58:54.877 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=b2678617ff4dcac7245d236b6302e57ba83a71cb6ea558c6
```

But I can't open the url. I have forwarded the port 8888 in my `docker-compose`, tried to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` and also tried to use the containers IP w/o success.

It feels like I am missing the obvious here … Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the sake of records as of 2020, I managed to have a working `django` setup with `Postgresql` in `docker-compose`:

#### development.py (settings.py)

```
INSTALLED_APPS += [
    "django_extensions",
]

SHELL_PLUS = "ipython"

SHELL_PLUS_PRINT_SQL = True

NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
    "--ip",
    "0.0.0.0",
    "--port",
    "8888",
    "--allow-root",
    "--no-browser",
]

IPYTHON_ARGUMENTS = [
    "--ext",
    "django_extensions.management.notebook_extension",
    "--debug",
]

IPYTHON_KERNEL_DISPLAY_NAME = "Django Shell-Plus"

SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS = [ # extra things to import in notebook
    ("module1.submodule", ("func1", "func2", "class1", "etc")),
    ("module2.submodule", ("func1", "func2", "class1", "etc"))

]

os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true" # only use in development
```

#### requirements.txt

```
django-extensions
jupyter
notebook
Werkzeug  # needed for runserver_plus
...
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.development
    command:
      - scripts/startup.sh
    volumes:
      - ...
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # webserver 
      - "8888:8888" # ipython notebook
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

From your host terminal run this command:

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Finally navigate to `http://localhost:8888/?token=<xxxx>` in the web browser of host.

Comment: The essential parts are `NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS` and to have port `8888` mapped outside from the container (`-p` param for example).

Comment: @n1_ async part is also needed for db statements

Comment: @n1_ needed for [django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/)

Comment: Instead of setting `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` in `settings.py`, I recommend moving it to `docker-compose exec -e DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE=true web python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`

Answer (score 3):

Got it to work, but why it does so is beyond me. Exposing the ports in the `docker-compose run` command did the trick.

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm -p 8888:8888 django python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I was under the impression exposing ports in my `local.yml` would open them also in containers started by `run`.

Comment: I have provided a MWE of `docker-compose`, `django`, `notebook`.

Comment: Thx. Gonna check it out on Monday. The weird thing with my solution was, that albeit the notebook would start and be accessible in the browser, none of the shell plus functionality was available, i. e. Module loading and stuff. I couldn't load any models of my app actually.

Comment: `run` will spin up a new container, I think you should use `exec`. All the `shell_plus` functionality is accessible in the provided solution.

Comment: Ok. It seems to work, although I can’t log into the notebook. The token won't be accepted. Which seems weird, all I am doing is to navigate to the token enriched url. You know why that might be? ... I tried to also enter the token manually, of course.

Comment: Did a restart and the notebook starts now. But I got the same `AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` error like before with my `run` solution.

Comment: I guess I know what's going on. I am also using Wagtail on top of Django and I think that’s the culprit. Running your solution on a vanilla Django works. Therefore I'll accept your answer ;-)

Comment: I am also using `wagtail` and it works fine. Though, no idea about the error you receive.

Comment: Ah, really? Ok, at least I know it's possible. May I ask if you use an `ClusterableModel` in your models? I suspect that one to be the offender…

Comment: No I don't have such kind of models

Answer (score 1):

The compose run command will per default not expose the defined service ports. From the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

> The [...] difference is that the docker-compose run command does not
> create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This
> prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the
> service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the
> --service-ports flag:
>
> ```
> docker-compose run --service-ports web python manage.py shell
> ```

You will therefore need to run

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm --service-ports django python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

It might also be that the default 8888 port is already used by a local jupyter server (e.g. one spun up by VS Code's jupyter notebook implementation. I therefore usually map to a different port in the settings.py NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS list. (In this case the port mapping in the compose file needs to be adjusted as well, of course, and there must not be another container running in the background with the same service definition as this might also occupy the port.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jupyter notebook like separated service:

```
jupyter_notebook:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: docker/dev/web/Dockerfile
  command: python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
  depends_on:
    - web
  ports:
  - 8888:8888 # ipython notebook
  env_file:
    - .env
```

after:

```
docker-compose logs -f 'jupyter_notebook'
```

and you will get access token in logs

Comment: Hi bandirom. Please explain your answer a bit more. What should we do with the YAML provided in your answer? Why does doing this help to open the URL that the original poster is trying to open? It looks like the original poster already has the access token, but can't open the URL.

Comment: Hi @SethDifley!  You can create separated instance for your notebook in docker-compose.yml like service.

Comment: In answer above, you shoud start jupyter manually. In this solution, you have a runned notebook already